# Is it possible to have an array or a list of geometric primitives in Java?

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

Consider drawing an image using a set of the primitive geometric shapes. The solution which I can think of is to combine the items into an array, iterate over it and call the draw method:

```
Object[] elements = {(new Ellipse2D.Double(200, 200, 40, 40)), 
                     (new Line2D.Double(10, 10, 100, 100)), 
                     (new Rectangle2D.Double(50,50,90,90))};

for (int j=0; j<elements.length; j++){ 
g2d.draw(elements[j]);
}
```

This should be possible if they all belong to the same parent class. But I was not able to confirm whether such a class exists.
Could you please clarify about this object class or maybe there is another way to make an array/list of the shapes?

Edit: Thank you all for the prompt answers! :)

Comment: Shape? Simply have a look at the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html

Comment: Use the Java [Polygon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html) class to define a line, rectangle, or ellipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First step is to look at the API docs for one of your types, say, [`Ellipse2D.Double`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.Double.html).

We can see this extends `Ellipse2D`, and clicking on that gives `RectangularShape`. That lists (direct) subclasses, but `Line2D` is not among them. You want the interface `Shape` and you're done.

Alternatively, look at the [`Graphics2D.draw`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#draw(java.awt.Shape)) method and observe that it declares the parameter as `Shape`.

You editor/IDE may also be able to give this information more directly.

Answer (score 3):

The draw method of class java.awt.Graphics2D take a java.awt.Shape interface as parameter.

The java.awt.Shape javadoc contains:

> All Known Implementing Classes:
>
> Arc2D, Arc2D.Double, Arc2D.Float, Area, BasicTextUI.BasicCaret,
> CubicCurve2D, CubicCurve2D.Double, CubicCurve2D.Float, DefaultCaret,
> Ellipse2D, Ellipse2D.Double, Ellipse2D.Float, GeneralPath, Line2D,
> Line2D.Double, Line2D.Float, Path2D, Path2D.Double, Path2D.Float,
> Polygon, QuadCurve2D, QuadCurve2D.Double, QuadCurve2D.Float,
> Rectangle, Rectangle2D, Rectangle2D.Double, Rectangle2D.Float,
> RectangularShape, RoundRectangle2D, RoundRectangle2D.Double,
> RoundRectangle2D.Float

So the following perfectly fits your need

```
java.awt.Shape[] elements = {
        new Ellipse2D.Double(200, 200, 40, 40),
        new Line2D.Double(10, 10, 100, 100), 
        new Rectangle2D.Double(50, 50, 90, 90)};
```

EDIT: fix in comment added

Comment: this works! i have just noticed that I've missed the word new in the array declaration: Shape[] elements = {(new Ellipse2D.Double(200, 200, 40, 40)), 
                     (new Line2D.Double(10, 10, 100, 100)), 
                     (new Rectangle2D.Double(50,50,90,90))};